# How to pass dynamic data in highcharts using flutter?

Tags: flutter, highcharts

I'm using **highcharts** library for my flutter application for different charts.

And want to know how to pass dynamic data into chart data.

Comment: do you mean live data to live chart ?

Comment: Hey katha, can you share your code I can see what kind of dynamic data you wanted to show in chart.

Comment: This article explained how to [working-with-data](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-intro#working-with-data) in Highcharts.

Comment: Yes, Live data for live chart